# Are the basic open sets of the Baire space closed?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

One way to describe the topology of the Baire space $\mathbb{B} = \omega^\omega$ is that the basic open sets are of the form $N_\eta = \left\{ f \in \omega^\omega \middle |\  \eta \subseteq f \right\}$ where $\eta \in \omega^{< \omega}$. Are the basic open sets closed?

I've seen it implied that they are, but it's not obvious to me that it would be the case.

Comment: If $\eta_1, \eta_2 \in \omega^k$, and $\eta_1 \neq \eta_2$, what is $N_{\eta_1} \cap N_{\eta_2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \notin N_\eta$. So $\eta \nsubseteq f$, so there is some $n$ in the domain of $\eta$ such that $\eta(n) \neq f(n)$. Now create $\eta'$ to be the partial function $\{(n, f(n)\}$ of one element. Then $f \in N_{\eta'}$ and if $g \in N_{\eta'}$ then $g(n)= f(n) \neq \eta(n)$ hence $\eta \nsubseteq g$, so $N_{\eta'} \cap N_\eta = \emptyset$.

So any non-member has an open neighbourhood that completely misses it, so $N_\eta$ is closed.